# Change the parent button name from context menu

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a custom right click context menu

I want to update the parent button caption when I clicked on any of the sub menu item

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Mname As String = "MyPopUpMenu"

Sub PopUpMenu()

    ' Create the custom right click menu.
    Call RClickMenu

    ' Display the popup menu.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Mname).ShowPopup
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Custom right click menu:

```
Sub RClickMenu()

Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
Dim SectionType As String
 = "Sections"

' Add the popup menu.
With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
     MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

    Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    With MenuItem
        .caption = "File Type"

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .caption = "File 1"
            .OnAction = "setCaption"
            .Parameter = "file1"
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .caption = "File 2"
            .OnAction = "setCaption"
            .Parameter = "file2"
        End With

    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Mouse down event when right clicked:

```
Public Sub btnFindSections_MouseDown(ByVal button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If button = 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.file.com"
    ElseIf button = 2 Then
        PopUpMenu
    End If
End Sub
```

Set caption method:

```
Sub setCaption()
    Select Case CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
    Case "Sections"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Name = "Sections" // Error saying item not found
    End Select
End Sub
```

Inside `setCaption()`, I need to find the parent button and change its caption from `Find files` to `Find Sections`

Comment: I tried playing with your 'PopUpMenu' and I am asking myself why do you use `On Error Resume Next` before the line `Application.CommandBars(Mname).ShowPopup`. Usually, an error may occur only if that specific `CommandBar` could be create twice. In such a situation it is good to delete it before creation, but I am curious what is the reason in your case...

Comment: @FaneDuru That line got copied from example I found I think. I need to check its significance

Comment: Try, please using `DeleteToolbar` in `ShowRightClickMenu` sub, just before the line `With Application.CommandBars.aDD(...`. The sub would look like: `Private Sub DeleteToolbar()` `On Error Resume Next` `Application.CommandBars(Mname).Delete`  `On Error GoTo 0` `End Sub`. Take care, there are 5 code lines. Here, `On Error Resume Next` is important for the case when such a bar does not exist...

Comment: @FaneDuru Any idea how to make the control button font to bold in right click menu? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677579/set-font-type-bold-to-context-menu-button-in-excel-vba

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I do not have time right now...

Comment: May I know why did you delete your question you mention above?

Comment: @FaneDuru I was making some edits to my answer. You can check now.

Comment: @FaneDuru Finally I managed to achieve the face id for context menu dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing of (in case of ActiveX button):

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object.Caption = "Lists"
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Name = "Lists"
```

In case of 'Form' Button, replace the same line with:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons("CommandButton1").Caption = "Lists"
```

In the above examples, the code uses the the button `Name`, like you requested.

If you need to find an ActiveX button using its `Caption`, you must need to use the next iteration code:

```
Sub TestButtonCaptionSearch()
  Dim but As OLEObject
    For Each but In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If but.Object.Caption = "CommandButton1" Then
            but.Object.Caption = "Lists": Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Error: Unable to get the buttons property of Worksheet class for `Form`

Comment: Error: Error: Unable to get the OLEOjects property of Worksheet class for for `Active X`

Comment: @kittu: What type is your button? Is it placed on a sheet, or on a Form? If on a sheet, like it looks probable, is it an activeX type or Form type?

Comment: Its an ActiveX button

Comment: @kittu: Then, do you want changing of its name, or its caption?

Comment: And are you looking for the button name or for the button caption?

Comment: Button caption .

Comment: This is different. I will update my answer code... Adapted!

Comment: If it still returns an error, this can only mean that you do not have an ActiveX button with "CommandButton1" name! Looking to your picture, your button name should be `""CommandButton1"`. Is this assumption incorect? You cannot search in a collection according to the element `Caption`! You can do that, but only through an iteration... Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Any example of iterating the collection? I am new to vba. Actually when I click on the button in design mode, I see button name as `=EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1","")`

Comment: You are right. Button name is different but it was showing `commandButton1` in design mode so got confused. Any idea how to set the action as well?

Comment: In order to "discover" the button name you must look not in the `Formula bar`! You must look on the same row, to the first box, where the cell address (or range Names) are shown (Name Box). I will show you how to deal with both situations (caption or name)...

Comment: I am afraid that an ActiveX button does not have a `FaceID` property. You can see its properties, going in `Developer` Ribbon Tab, pressing `Design Mode`, selecting the button and then pressing `Properties` button on the ribbon, or `Properties` of the right click context menu. But, did the updated code solve your problem? You did not (directly) confirmed...

Comment: Yes updated code you provided is working now. Thanks

Comment: @kittu: So, we here, when a piece of code answered the question, have the habit to tick the code left side check box, to make it **accepted answer**. And vote it up if we have the necessary notoriety and the efort for answering deserves it. Doing that, when somebody else looks for something similar, will know that the code answered the question...

Comment: I was going to do that. Also, I will  post another question for action type.

Comment: @kittu: If you tag me (@FaneDuru), I can try helping... But you did not make the code the accepted answer...

Comment: Posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643214/how-to-copy-and-paste-the-activex-button-using-excel-vba Can you please have a look?