# Copy and paste the activeX button

Tags: excel, vba

I have custom right click menu from which when I click sub menu item I want to open a pop window to allow user to enter destination or reference cell to copy and paste the parent button (activeX)

**User clicked on "Copy to":**

**Pop up opened:** Allow user to select any cell on sheet or manually enter destination cell ref.

When I click on "Ok" button, a copy of button should be in `E14`

Custom menu:

```
Sub RClickMenu()

Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
Dim ListType As String
ListType = "Lists"

' Add the popup menu.
With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
     MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

     ' CODE TYPE.
    Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    With MenuItem
        .caption = "Buttons edit option"

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .caption = "copy button"
        End With

    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Mouse down event on right click:

```
Public Sub btnFindSections_MouseDown(ByVal button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If button = 1 Then
    ElseIf button = 2 Then
        CreatePopUpMenu
    End If
End Sub
```

**Code to Open popup:**

```
Sub getCellReference()

Dim rng As Range
Dim FormatRuleInput As String

'Get A Cell Address From The User to Get Number Format From
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
      Title:="Copy Code to Cell", _
      Prompt:="Select the cell reference to copy to:", _
      Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

After opening the pop up and getting the cell reference, how do I copy the button to new cell?

Comment: What does not work in your attempt/scenario? Do you only need some hints in order to accomplish what (we understand) you need?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am able to open the pop up to get the cell reference but not sure how to copy/move the parent button(Find Series) to new cell reference I got from pop up.

Comment: @FaneDuru Updated the code but there are few issues like functionality of new button is missing completely

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303944/4717755) help?

Comment: @PeterT I have fixed issue for copying the button but newly copied button's functionality is missing. Any idea?

Comment: None of the copied shapes keeps any functionality, except their format (shape, dimensions, captions etc.). The newly created control is another object, another entity. It has its own events which must be used... In order to be copied where you need, you firstly select the cell where you want to be positioned. It will become its `TopLeftCell` property...

Comment: @FaneDuru I think its because the new button is created with new name. In that case I need to add the right click functionality to new button dynamically. Any idea on that?

Comment: Of course... it is enough to write the event code in the page module, for the new name. You need a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3'

Comment: @FaneDuru I didn't get you. Page module as in module other than class module? Also Ext 5.3 is for handling the functionality for new button?

Comment: I wanted to say Sheet module. There where the button events code appears. In order to programmatically write in module you need the reference I mentioned

Comment: Should I post a piece of code able to do what you need for event creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code to create the event for the newly created button. You will call the `Sub` using your button name. During its copying or after. You can test now the code for the already copies button. But it the code will return an error if you try running it line by line. Run it at once (F5). And be careful to not run it twice before deleting the already created event.

```
Private Sub AddSheetEventButMouseDown(butName As String)
   'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility x.x'
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wProj As VBIDE.VBProject, wCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim wMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'the sheet where the event must be created!
                         'I used active sheet only for testing...
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set wProj = .VBProject
        Set wCom = wProj.VBComponents(sh.codename)
        Set wMod = wCom.CodeModule
        With wMod
             .AddFromString "Private Sub " & butName & "_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)" & vbCrLf & _
                            "    If Button = 1 Then" & vbCrLf & _
                            "            MsgBox ""Left clicked""" & vbCrLf & _
                            "    ElseIf Button = 2 Then" & vbCrLf & _
                            "            CreatePopUpMenu" & vbCrLf & _
                            "    End If" & vbCrLf & _
                            "End Sub"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

It is designed to exactly create the event you need...

You can also create the Click event in the same step, building the string in a way to also contain it.

This piece of code will (simpler) copy the button and call the above `Sub` to create the event:

```
Private Sub testCopyButton(address As String)
 Dim sh As Worksheet, but As Shape, butName As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
  butName = "Just_copied"
  Set but = sh.Shapes("btnFindSections")
  but.Copy
  sh.Paste Destination:=sh.Range(address)
  On Error Resume Next
   sh.Shapes(sh.Shapes.count).Name = butName
   If Err.Number = 70 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "On the sheet " & sh.Name & ", a button named " & butName & " already exists..." & vbCrLf & _
               "You must delete it, or choose another button name and run the code again.", vbInformation, _
               "Wrong button name"
               sh.Shapes(sh.Shapes.count).Delete 'the last created button is deleted
               Exit Sub
   End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  AddSheetEventButMouseDown butName
End Sub
```

And the test `Sub`, calling the above one, will be:

```
Sub testCopyButton()
   testCopyButton "O15" 'use here your cell address where to be copied
                        'the sheet name can be also sent and the sub
                        'making the copying needs another parameter...
End Sub
```

Comment: @kittu: Wait a little. I will post the other pieces to have all the puzzle...

Comment: @kittu: Please, refresh this page, to be using the last versions. I made some modifications after testing...

Comment: I am getting error: `user defined type not defined`

Comment: @kittu:  Any button is a shape! Do you have a button named `"btnFindSeries"` on sheet `sh`? How did  you define `sh`? Is it the active sheet? It can be any sheet, but you must check these aspects... Did you use the variable definition from my code: `Dim but as Shape`? Otherwise, VBA may return such an error...

Comment: Ok let me check again

Comment: @kittu: I adapted a little the code, in order to warn in case of running it, but a button with the name you want to allocate to the last created one exists...

Comment: I need to generate button name dynamically may be with counter++ and assign the right click functionality to it.

Comment: @kittu: I do not understand what you mean... Do you want creating more buttons? If yes, which will be your problem? If you have a way to generate names for these many buttons, you can iterate as many times for as many buttons you need to create. The code logic does not change... But you did not confirm that the code works like it is, for a new button with event generation, like I understood that you asked...

Comment: Ok I will try to generate with counter or date time and iterate the list of buttons as you said. End user can copy and create n number of buttons

Comment: @kittu: "But you did not confirm that the code works like it is, for a new button with event generation, like I understood that you asked..."

Comment: I am still facing some issues. As you said I need to add Ext 5.3. How do I add? From tools menu?

Comment: @kittu: a logic approach would be to firstly solve those 'some issues' and only then looking for improvements... Go in VBE -> Tools -> References... and scroll down until you see the recommended reference, tick it and press `OK`. Then, it would be good to save the workbook... The reference is added anyhow, but if something wrong happens before saving, it will lose it.

Comment: I am not finding Go in VBE -> Tools -> References in my excel 2019. I think the error is for user defined types

Comment: @kittu:  You have to **go** in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor) and use the `Tools` menu from there... Alt + F11.

Comment: Thanks so much. After enabling ext 5.3 its working. Sorry I am new to vba

Comment: @kittu: Glad to here that it works for you, too! Being new, it is good to also learn focusing on important issues and the logic succession of what is to be done. Optimizations should go only after seeing the code working... :)